# How to create key-value string sequence from another plain sequence in XPath 2.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I needs an XSLT function to create key-value strings sequence `( 'key1_val1', 'key2_val2', 'key3_val3' )` from plain strings sequence `( 'key1', 'val1', 'key2', 'val2', 'key3', 'val3' )`.

I was stopped on the following code and have no ideas to continue:

```
<xsl:function name="bx:generate-pairs" as="xs:string*">
    <xsl:param name="seq" as="xs:string*"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="for $key in $seq return ..."/>
</xsl:function>
```

XSLT processor Saxon 9.3

Comment: I needs an input .xml sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
for $i in (1 to count($seq))[. mod 2 = 1] return concat($seq[$i], '_', $seq[$i + 1])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I feel it's a mind deadlock due to overwork -_-;